# How to calculate percentage in View Page of a MVC App in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

My view currently looks similar to this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>

<div class="list-group">

    @foreach (var x in Model)
    {
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            @int passPercentage = x.PassCount/(x.FailedCount + x.Passcount)*100;
            <span>passPercentage</span>
        </a>
    }

</div>
```

But run-time fails telling 'invalid expression term int' (in the line where I calculate the passPercentage)

One option I can think of is to calculate this percentage at the server side and pass on to the view.

Are there any other alternatives If I wish to do this operation at client (view side) ?

Comment: it needs to be `@{ int passPercentage = ....; }` and `<span<@passPercentage</span>` - but that code should be in the controller method, not the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thanks. Meaning, even simple calculations need to be done at the controller / server side ? Cant we give some data to the view - for it to operate on its capacity ?

Comment: The controller is responsible fro sending the correct data for use in the view (and what you want in the view is the calculated value), so it should be in the controller (where it can also be unit tested etc). But it can be in the view if you want.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Stephan :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To declare a variable, you need to be inside a code block (i.e. `@{ ... }`, and then to access the variable inside an html element, you need to use `@passPercentage`

```
@foreach (var x in Model)
{
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        @{ int passPercentage = x.PassCount/(x.FailedCount + x.Passcount)*100; }
        <span>@passPercentage</span>
    </a>
}
```

Alternatively, you could have declared in the `foreach` code block (not inside the `<a>` element)

```
@foreach (var x in Model)
{
    int passPercentage = x.PassCount/(x.FailedCount + x.Passcount)*100;
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        <span>@passPercentage</span>
    </a>
}
```

However, the controller is responsible for passing the correct data to the view, so ideally the calculation should be done on the server, and the calculated value sent to the view

Comment: Movd the processing to the controller side finally.. though it can also be done on the client view :) Thanks Stephan.